# How do I run simple perl script on dotcloud, i.e. not psgi standard

Tags: perl, dotcloud

For the record I don't really know perl. I've deployed Rails apps on dotcloud. Here is what I am trying to do;

Currently I work for a SaaS. We run scripts (perl/python/php) on an external shared server to do what our software cannot. We need to move the script off of the shared server, and dotcloud seemed like a good option.

However I have nearly no experience running perl. It looks like I cannot just move the perl script, as dotcloud says that runs any perl using the psgi standard;

From dotcloud documentation: "The Perl service can host any Perl web application compatible with the PSGI standard."

I moved the script to my own hosting account and it worked but it appears to run too slow. It seems like a virtual host/server is the best option which was why I was excited about dotcloud, but since I'm not qualified to do modify perl myself (i.e. modify it to meet psgi standard) I need another option.

I question is 2 fold - how easy/difficult is it to make a simple perl script psgi standard OR are there any other virtual hosting options for perl with fewer restrictions?

Comment: What is your existing script doing? CGI?

Comment: parsing an excel file, and using it to generate SOAP calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a normal perl script that doesn't need to be served from a web server then you should use the `perl-worker` service. Using the `perl worker` service is meant for normal perl scripts so you don't need to worry about psgi because that is only for web stuff.

Here is a link to the perl worker page on dotcloud: 
http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.9/services/perl-worker/

This will give you access to a normal perl environment, and you can run what ever you need, cron jobs, shell, etc.